# sum of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Can any of you help me?
I have some problem with this exercise of "Probability and Statistics" :

> Calculate the probability density function (PDF) of $Z=X+Y$
>
> where $Y$ is discrete random variable which is be equal to $-1,1$ with equal probability;
> $X$ is standard Gaussian random variable independent from $Y$.

I know that the PDF of sum of two continuous independent variables is given by the convolution of the marginal PDF
$f_z(z)=f_x*f_y$
but if one on the two variable is discrete what should I do?
thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one variable is discrete, you can use the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) to preform the integration:
$$P(X=x) = \frac{1}{2}\delta(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(x+1)$$
Down-votes from purist mathematicians in 3.. 2.. 1..

Comment: ok,so i can convolve fx*fy?

Comment: @lui4 - Yes. you can use the Dirac delta as if it were regular function.

Comment: Another question of the same exercise.
X (standard gaussian variable) is indipendent from y (discrete variable, but is Y also indipendent from X?

Comment: @lui4 - yes independence is commutative. Also, if you like an answer, you can upvote it as well.

Comment: ok,how i can vote an answer? i'm sorry,but i'm new

Comment: Just click the arrows on the side of the question - up means you like the answer, down means this is a really bad one.

Comment: however i've just resolve the integral and the result of fz(z)=(1/2)(density-Normal distribuition of (z-1) + density-normal distribuition of (z+1)). is it correct? thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 There should be no objections from purists: use of $\delta$ can be made rigorous in the (Schwartz) sense of distributions.  Integration by parts of the convolution of the PDFs produces an integral which is the product of the derivative of the Gaussian PDF and the Heaviside function, both of which are integrable (even Riemann integrable).

Comment: Did someone _really_ think that "purist mathematicians" would object to the use of Dirac's delta function?  I thought the present year was 2013, not 1950.  I guess whoever wrote this answer hasn't noticed anything that's happened in the past 63 years.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - In my quantum mechanics class, the mathematicians always insisted we (physicists) stop calling it a function :)